# Cannot get Jquery ajax response

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my full html context.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 

<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>Test page</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('http://10.10.10.10:8123/BMreport.txt', function (data) {
                alert("callback");
            });
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
    <body> 
        <p>Test Page</p>
    </body> 
</html>
```

well the alert doesnt shows up. The BMreport.txt is in JSon format. cannot figure why...
--------------solved------------
10.10.10.10:8123 is different domain from this site. After putting them in same domain it works

Comment: Is your browser reporting any errors?

Comment: If your workstation is not of the _same origin_ as http://10.10.10.10:8123, then you're out of luck. Read about **Same Origin Policy**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Alex. Ok, I found the reason. 10.10.10.10:8123 and this html is on different site. after putting them on same site it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console for any errors, or use $.ajax() instead of $.getJSON and supply an 'error'-function. Most likely, something goes wrong when jQuery tries to parse your json.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://10.10.10.10:8123/BMreport.txt', 
        success: function (data) {
            alert("callback");
        },
        error: function(req, err) {
            alert(req.responseText); // This will alert whatever your .txt-file outputs
        }
    });
});
```